# How to Debug Functions for an interface PHP

Tags: php, magento2

I have an issue within Magneto where Tax seems to be added twice for a product tier price in category pages. Im trying to debug why this is happening so have looked through a few files:

Template shows `renderAmountMinimal()` function being used:

```
$block->renderAmountMinimal();
```

Block code for this function:

```
public function renderAmountMinimal()
{
    $id = $this->getPriceId() ? $this->getPriceId() : 'product-minimal-price-' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();

    $amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getValue($this->getSaleableItem());

    print_r($amount);

    $amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getAmount($this->getSaleableItem());
    if ($amount === null) {
        return '';
    }

    return $this->renderAmount(
        $amount,
        [
            'display_label'     => __('As low as'),
            'price_id'          => $id,
            'include_container' => false,
            'skip_adjustments' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

Returns an incorrect value in the object for `$amount`. Strangely getValue() seems to show the correct amount however. Then so i wanted to take a look at `$this->minimalPriceCalculator` and see what is going on within getAmount however am unsure how to debug / see whats going on within here as the file looks like below:

```
namespace Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface;

interface MinimalPriceCalculatorInterface
{
/**
 * Get raw value for "as low as" price
 *
 * @param SaleableInterface $saleableItem
 * @return float|null
 */
public function getValue(SaleableInterface $saleableItem);

/**
 * Return structured object with "as low as" value
 *
 * @param SaleableInterface $saleableItem
 * @return AmountInterface|null
 */
public function getAmount(SaleableInterface $saleableItem);
}
```

I have checked the `SaleableInterface` but it looks similar to above, aswell as every file thereafter after. The issue seems to go quite deep just want to know where to look so I can see why its going wrong?

Comment: where do you have your magento2 installed? VM, docker, localhost?

Comment: I have it on a ubuntu web server for dev and a staging on a centos VM. Both show same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this tutorial for [debugging](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/docker/docker-phpstorm-debug.html) with PHPStorm (or as guidance for other IDE).

The idea in magento2 is that this interfaces are used for [dependency injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) where the Magento framwork initializes them for you. So by running the debugger as above you will be directed to the generated classes.

If you just want to see the classes you can go on your server in the root document at `var/generation/Magento` and search there for the file. This are usually generated when you run `magento setup:di:compile` in the CLI.

Comment: Awesome i will take a look. Under a tight deadline as of an hour ago so may just go about hiding this block on category pages but thanks for your help i will come back to this when i can!

Comment: Im guessing its now generated folder now var/generation as of 2.2.x

Comment: I think in all magento2 so as 2.0.x, I'm using 2.1.x now for instance

Comment: I mean generated now replaced var/generation from what i can tell.

Comment: Do you recommend any other free IDE's? I have a PHP evaluation spinning up and am going to try NetBeans maybe as free alternative?

Comment: So PHPStorm is by faaaar the best option here, but as free alternative I've tried also a little with eclipse and NetBeans and in the end NB is a little better (keep in mind I've tried this IDEs with PHP 2-3 years ago). In the end you can use also something basic like `vim` if you feel confident enough :). Other editors that people use: Atom, Sublime. And I don't know anything about VisualStudio for the PHP (just the C stuff and some webdesign)

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help ill give phpstorm a go for a 30 days and may have to purchase if i cant handle Netbeans after ha